# Stop 0x0000007B error when installing xp on a dell laptop

Tags: windows-xp, installation

I get an error when installing from a Windows XP CD to my Dell laptop.

The error is:

```
stop: 0x0000007B (0xF78D2524, 0xC0000034, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
```

Why is this problem occurring and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Source [Advanced troubleshooting for "Stop error code 0x0000007B (INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE)" errors in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324103)

> This step-by-step article describes how to troubleshoot "Stop 0x0000007B" error messages in Windows XP. This article describes issues that can cause this Stop error including boot sector viruses and device driver issues or hardware issues. If you cannot resolve the problem after you review these issues, use the general troubleshooting steps that appear at the end of the article.

Please read this article and follow the troubleshooting steps.